# Proving that $\left(X(v,v)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ defines a norm on a vector space where X is a positive-definite bilinear form.

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Want to show: If $X$ is a positive-definite bilinear form on a vector space $G$ with real-valued scalars and $v\in G$, then $\left(X(v,v)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ defines a norm on $G$.

Thus far I have three of the four properties of a norm. What remains to be shown is that $\left(X(u+v,u+v)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq \left(X(u,u)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} + \left(X(v,v)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$. I need a hint on this remaining property.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz?

Comment: To elaborate on the other comment: What you have here is an **inner product** for which the Cauchy Schwarz inequality (automatically) holds (look it up if you do not know it). This inequality implies what you want relatively easily.

Comment: How do I know that X is symmetric?